# Why can't the compiler prevent these runtime cast exceptions?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime newYears = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
            PromoteEmployee(newYears);
        }

        public static void PromoteEmployee(object o)
        {
            // At this point, the compiler doesn't know exactly what type of object o refers to. So the compiler allows the code to compile...

            Employee e = (Employee)o; // this results in invalid cast exception at runtime
        }
    }

    class Employee
    {

    }
```

But I think the compiler does know or it can easily know by looking at all places where this method is being referenced as to what type is being passed to PromoteEmployee (at least for such cases where no runtime conditions decide what type gets passed in)

So why should casting exceptions be left to occur at runtime when the compiler with some extra logic easily pick them up ?

Comment: The compiler does not know about references from other assemblies, consider it as an assembly and some other application calling this method with any of the types so how do you want compiler stop building this library?

Comment: Your compiler cannot always know, who is referencing your assembly. Further more sometimes people use reflection to call methods, which  would make alot of trouble for the compiler.

Comment: What actual use case you are trying to solve here? Or you are just experimenting something? Compiler doesn't look into your code to understand what your are trying to do with what object. DateTime can be casted to object so it compiles method call and in object can be casted to Employee that's why it compiles method body.

Comment: If you are also asking how to avoid the exception, you can wrap that code in `if (o is Employee) { }`

Comment: Compiler is responsible for compile time analysis of code. Compiler do not know passed object type as it'll consider as object.

Comment: @RufusL : With pattern matching in c# 7.0, it has been more simplified like `if (o is Employee e) e.property`

Comment: This sort of code analysis is not the job of a compiler.  Your example is simplistic, however you can come up with much more complicated examples that would produce the same error.  To do a proper job it would have to run through every permutation of the code.  Furthermore, the case you're putting forward is simply an example of bad programming.  If your method accepted a proper type rather than object then you would get a compile error.

Comment: I understand that it will not be able to tell in all cases. What I am asking like for the code sample above, where it is within the same assembly, where there is no conditional logic dictating what type of object gets passed in, don't you think these runtime exceptions can be prevented (by a smarter compiler) at compile time itself ?

Comment: @C.Dhruv You can always pass child object to parent type reference, the issue is you are casting it wrongly here which is your responsibility.

Comment: A smart compiler isn't going to help a bad programmer, if you're finding yourself using the object type to resolve application design issues, I'd suggest you rethink your application design.  If you want to develop in a loosely typed language, try javascript, however you can expect runtime errors in such environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you basically want is for the compiler to check everywhere in your code where you call your function, then check the passed parameter type and then for every call go to every line inside the function where the parameter is used and check if the receiving type is able to be converted or casted to every type it is checked against.

Possible? Maybe, but only in a handful of cases that wouldn't make worth the extra compile time it would take.

Also, imagine this case:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime newYears = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
        object ob = newYears;
        PromoteEmployee(ob);
    }
```

This means the compiler would also had to go through every single value assignation the parameter suffers before being passed to the function.

So, bottom line: yeah, it is technically possible, but is not worth the effort, the time, and would encourage bad programming practices.